# Extending standard library modules

Tags: module, lua

Is it possible to extend (or even override) standard library modules. I'd like to be able to do something like

```
-- eggs.lua
table.spam = function(tab)
    return tab[1]
end
```

and then

```
-- ham.lua
require('eggs')
table.spam({2,7,1,3})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, although the recommendation would be not to modify the standard library namespace, but use `tablex` instead as [some libraries do](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.tablex.html).

Comment: actually, returning an anonymous or local table instead would be even preferable, cause then you can select the name when requiring like so: `local tablex=require'eggs'`. when using a `__index` metatable you can even pass through any unknown (=unwrapped) calls to `table`